# JointTrajectoryResult not defined?

Tags: ros, joint-trajectory-controller, pr2-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to get the result of a JointTrajectoryAction. The my_joint_trajecotry_action_client.get_result() returns a message of type JointTrajectoryResult, but it has no meaningful fields. What's the right way to get the result of a JointTrajectoryAction?

Thanks!

Huan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10386/jointtrajectoryresult-not-defined?/) by [liuhuanjim013](https://answers.ros.org/users/446/liuhuanjim013/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not familiar with using JointTrajectoryAction in particular, but according to the [docs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joint_trajectory_action), the result is supposed to be empty. This means that you would use the state of the ActionClient to determine the result of your command to the controller. For example, some states that you could get (e.g. with `my_joint_trajectory_action_client.get_state()` ) could be `GoalStatus.SUCCEEDED` or `GoalStatus.ABORTED`. There are other states that you could get; see the [actionlib](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib) docs for details.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liuhuanjim013](https://answers.ros.org/users/446/liuhuanjim013/) on 2011-06-23**:
Thanks Eric! This is exactly what I need :)